# PySpark round off timestamps to full hours?

Tags: time, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I am interested in rounding off timestamps to full hours. What I got so far is to round to the nearest hour. For example with this:

```
df.withColumn("Full Hour", hour((round(unix_timestamp("Timestamp")/3600)*3600).cast("timestamp")))
```

But this "round" function uses HALF_UP rounding. This means: 23:56 results in 00:00 but I would instead prefer to have 23:00. Is this possible? I didn't find an option field how to set the rounding behaviour in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. Hour function returns by default an hour component of a timestamp.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = (sc
    .parallelize([Row(Timestamp='2016_08_21 11_59_08')])
    .toDF()
    .withColumn("parsed", to_timestamp("Timestamp", "yyyy_MM_dd hh_mm_ss")))

df2 = df.withColumn("Full Hour", hour(unix_timestamp("parsed").cast("timestamp")))

df2.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|          Timestamp|             parsed|Full Hour|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|2016_08_21 11_59_08|2016-08-21 11:59:08|       11|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
```